# Why is Claire a Dinosaur activist in Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom and Dominion?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom, jurassic-world-dominion

In the *Jurassic World* trilogy, after the horrors from bringing back the infamous dinosaur theme park, we suddenly see Claire as an activist. She is actively protesting to protect the dinosaurs, even trying to save them in *Dominion*. What I do not understand is: What made her want to do it? With her previous dino-related experiences:

- It made her job more stressful (Wanted to mention this, though it will be the least bad one listed)
- Dinosaurs almost killed her.
- Dinosaurs almost killed her nephews.
- Dinosaurs have given her horrible memories

So, why does she suddenly have this belief that they need to be protected? Why is she not like how Ellen Ripley is towards the xenomorphs, having hatred towards them and wanting them gone for good? It is interesting how she appears to not have any PTSD.

Comment: Some related insights can be found [here](https://jurassicoutpost.com/claire-dearing-unrepentant-new-dinosaur-protection-group-updates/).

Comment: Was it the dinosaurs that were responsible for almost getting her killed or was it greedy unscrupulous corporations who messed with nature without understanding it and put profit above the safety and well-being of their employees, their customers, and the dinosaurs? Was it the dinosaurs or was it the people trying to turn them into weapons?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Don't be shocked, but you're actually writing an answer.

Comment: @Joachim Any reservations to forming that out into a proper answer?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I have, since it doesn't provide a straight-forward answer.

Answer (score 2):

The overarching theme of the Jurassic Park/World movies (specifically the first of their respective trilogies) is that **trying to control wild nature is an act of hubris**, and the events in the movies are the consequences of losing that control. This also factors in the greed and laziness that leads to the lack of proper fallback scenarios. In short, it is not the dinosaurs who are the villains, but rather the park owners, chasing profit while risking the lives of everyone involved in the process.

Someone who takes that lesson to heart would then conclude that **nature needs to run its own free course**. This is what Claire is actively working towards.

Your bullet points only make sense if you assume that Claire's character did not change since her initial introduction, which suggests to me that you've not really seen her character arc.

In regards to your comparison with Ripley in Alien, Claire understands that the dinosaurs are not being malicious, they are simply trying to survive the way they know how. When finally given the chance in Dominion, they don't go out of their way to harm humans and simply exist in their own way.

Xenomorphs on the other hand actively seek out humans to use for parasitic breeding purposes. Alien also takes place in a spaceship where coexistence is simply not possible in such a small space. Thirdly, the general theme and overall message of the movies are completely different.